# Internal Links within IFrame doesn't working in iphone safari browser

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

The source code is :

```
<iframe id="privacy-frame" frameborder="0"
   src="http://www.cnn.com/partners/mobile/v2/privacy.policy/"
   style="width: 100%; background-color:#fff">
</iframe>
```

When i try to browse the page http://mobile-demo.turner.com/election/tos.html in iphone the internal links doesn't work.
But if i try to browse the page with src URL(http://www.cnn.com/partners/mobile/v2/privacy.policy/) it works.

Is this some issue with iFrame on iphone? Same code does work on Android browser or desktop browser.

Comment: Did you check it on an iPad as well, and does the problem occur on that, too? If so, can you make a live demo on http://jsbin.com ? I don't have an iPhone, but do have an iPad.

Comment: Correct. It doesn't work on ipad also.

Comment: So, where is the live demo?